# How to parse and extract the date from a string with several other elements

Tags: c, arrays, string, date

I have a string in C and I want to extract only the dates from it. I am trying to use `strcat` but I think it's adding the dates together. I'm not sure what exactly the problem is.

The string I'm trying to parse is `"CoursesExams=[101,28/4/2016,A;201,3/5/2016,A;110,5/5/2016;103,5/5/2016,A;120,6/5/2016,D;132,7/5/2016,B]"` and I only want the dates. I want something like `28/4/2016`, `3/5/2016` etc. but I'm getting numbers like 50, 56, 47.

```
    char string[1000] = "CoursesExams=[101,28/4/2016,A;201,3/5/2016,A;110,5/5/2016;103,5/5/2016,A;120,6/5/2016,D;132,7/5/2016,B]";
    int NumOEle = sizeof(string) / sizeof(char);
    char dates[1000] = "";
    int check = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NumOEle; i++) {
        if (string[i] == ',') {
            check++;
        }
        if (check == 1) {
            strcat(dates, string + i + 1);
            check = 0;
        }
        if (string[i] == ';') {
            check = 0;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", dates[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you want to strip the `[]`, split at `;` into substrings, then from each substring take the second item when splitting at `,` - is that correct?

Comment: Design a state-machine. You'll need only a handfull of states, recognising {number-digits, comma,semicolon, slash, [, ] }

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes that's exactly it

Comment: @wildplasser do you mean like a switch statement? I'm sorry that I don't know much of this stuff, I'm still pretty basic

Comment: @OmarEl-Habbak: not necessarily, but often you end up with a `for(...) { switch() {.. } }` construct.

Answer (score 2):

Could use a direct, yet inefficient `sscanf()` and `"%n"` to detect scan success

```
void printf_dates(const char *s) {
  while (*s) {
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(s, "%*2[0-9]/%*2[0-9]/%*4[0-9]%n", &n);
    // If parsing made it to the end 
    if (n > 0) {
      printf("Date <%.*s>\n", n, s);
      // To extract the day and month
      int day, month
      sscanf(s, "%d/%d", &day, &month);
      s += n;
    } else {
      s++;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage

```
printf_dates("CoursesExams=[101,28/4/2016,A;201,3/5/2016,A;110,5/5/2016;103,5/5/2016,A;120,6/5/2016,D;132,7/5/2016,B]");
```

Expected result

```
Date <28/4/2016>
Date <3/5/2016>
Date <5/5/2016>
Date <5/5/2016>
Date <6/5/2016>
Date <7/5/2016>
```

---

Details:

```
sscanf(s, "%*2[0-9]/%*2[0-9]/%*4[0-9]%n", &n);
"%*2[0-9]"  scan but not save due to `*`, 1 to 2 characters in the set `0`-`9`
"/"  scan a '/'
"%*4[0-9]"  scan but not save due to `*`, 1 to 4 characters in the set `0`-`9`
"%n"  save into the matching `int *` argument the offset of the scan.
```

Variable `n` only changed if all prior scanning succeeded.

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the job, but do you have any recommendations on how to better understand the method you used (sscanf and %n)?

Comment: @OmarEl-Habbak Answer amended.  Research [sscanf](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=sscanf&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

Comment: I did some research and understood the part that you specified in the "details" section. What I'm having trouble understanding is the print statement itself. Why did we include the string in the print statement if we already parsed the numbers into the int "n"? I'm asking because I want to store the days and months of the extracted dates into respective arrays in order to perform numerical operations on them. Therefore when I tried to access them via "n" so I could place them into days and months arrays, the output was bizarre. The string must have sth to do with it

Comment: @OmarEl-Habbak {we already parsed the numbers into the int "n"} --> The above code did not parse the numbers into `n`.  `n` contains the count of characters scanned.  `printf("%.*s", n, s);` prints the first `n` characters of `s` which is a _date_.

Comment: @OmarEl-Habbak “I want to store the days and months of the extracted dates into respective arrays in order to perform numerical operations on them “ is a new goal, not in the original question whose code was extracting the data as a some text.  “when I tried to access them via "n" so I could place them into days and months arrays “ is unclear.  Code amended to extract the day and month.